# Using map::find when 0 is an acceptable value

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have the following map in c++

```
std::map<string,int> mymap;
```

after inserting several values into it I then want to be able to search for a value in the map. I can use the find function to accomplish this

```
std::cout << "a => " << mymap.find("a")->second << '\n';
```

The problem with this is that find returns 0 when I search for a key that doesn't exist. I may want to insert a key with a value of 0 but I also need to know if a certain key does not exist in the map. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: `find` does not return 0 if the key doesn't exist. It returns `end()`. You need to check for that and handle it separately.

Answer (score 1):

## `std::map::find` is not doing what you think it's doing.

When you call `find` on a key that does not exist, the iterator returned is an invalid iterator; it does not point to a valid object. So any operations you attempt to perform on this object is undefined behavior, and (probably) an access to invalid memory.

The way you should be using `find` is to take the iterator and compare it to the map's `end` iterator to make sure it's valid.

```
std::map<std::string, int> mymap;

if(auto it = mymap.find("a"); it != mymap.end()) {//C++17 Initialized-If statement syntax
    std::cout << "a => " << it->second << std::endl;
}

//Old Syntax
std::map<std::string, int> mymap;

auto it = mymap.find("a"); 
if(it != mymap.end()) {
    std::cout << "a => " << it->second << std::endl;
}
```